# Substitutability for formala's variables with both free and bound occurrences

Tags: first-order-logic, substitution

I'm pretty clear with definition of **substitutability** for primary cases, within which the target variable to be replaced is totally free or completely bound, all over the formula.

For example, assume we're gonna find $\phi_{t}^{x}$ (Let $S$ be a unary function):

1- $x$ is bound and not free in $\phi$: $\phi:\equiv \forall x(x=y \rightarrow Sx = Sy)$ where $t=S0$

So, $\phi_{t}^{x} = (S0=y \rightarrow SS0 = Sy)$. But in view of the `substitutability test`, we can say *$t$ is substitutable in $\phi$ instead of $x$.*

2- $x$ is free in $\phi$ and $y$ does occur in $t$: $\phi:\equiv \forall y(x=y \rightarrow Sx = Sy)$ where $t=Sy$

So, $\phi_{t}^{x} = \forall y(Sy=y \rightarrow SSy = Sy)$. In view of the `substitutability test`, *$t$ is NOT substitutable in $\phi$ instead of $x$.*

But I'm not completely clear about "partially-free occurrences" of $x$:

3- $x$ is partially-free (or partially-bound): $\phi:\equiv x=y \rightarrow (\forall x)(Sx = Sy)$ where $t=Sy$

In this case, one is authorized to replace first $x$ with $t$ (because its a free occurrence), but not the second one (due to its bound property). Therefore, `it can't pass the substitutability test, in overall case`. Mathematically:

$\phi_{t}^{x} = Sy=y \rightarrow (SSy = Sy)$

> So, can I conclude results below, in summary?
>
> Substitutability is
>
> 1- defined
>
> 2- undefined
>
> 3- undefined

Comment: In the third case, the result must be : $\phi_t^x := Sy=y \to (\forall x)(Sx=Sy)$.

Comment: Thanks... But what about the overall result of substitutability case?... So, the substitutability is defined for the third case, by your trick, right?

Comment: The details are : $t$ is *substitutable for* $x$ in $(α →β)$ iff it is substitutable for $x$ in both $α$ and $β$. And $t$ is *substitutable for* $x$ in $∀y α$ iff either : (a) $x$ does not occur free in $∀y α$, or (b) $y$ does not occur in $t$ and $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $α$. Thus, calculate...

Comment: We have that : $Sy$ is subst for $x$ in $x=y$ and it is subst in $(∀x)(Sx=Sy)$ because $x$ is **not** free in it.

Comment: We have to recall that substitution is always defined : $(∀y α)^x_t = ∀y α$ if $x = y$ and $=∀y (α^x_t)$ if $x \ne y$.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion! By the trick, there will be only one $x$ which is substitutable, then overall x=y→(∀z)(Sz=Sy) will be substitutable. But if we do not use the trick, $t$ will not be substitutable, because it couldn't be replaced for second $x$. But If I've understood truly, first and second $x$ are independent. So, the first argument is true and overall $(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ is substitutable. Do you confirm it?

Comment: NO; $Sy$ is overall substitutable for $x$ because there are **no** $Qy$ quantifiers that can "capture" the $y$. The second occurrence of $x$ is not *free* and thus must be "skipped" because we cannot substitute a bound var.

Comment: The subst test must be performed only on the free occurrences of the $x$.

Comment: Much appreciated for your contribution.